# Is it possible to create a multi-account set up using aws-cdk?

Tags: amazon-web-services, devops, aws-cdk

I am creating a new project from scratch and I would like to use IaC with cdk. I am choosing a multi-account configuration and I would like to deploy all of it from cdk. is it possible?

I have been checking lots of aws documentation related to cdk i haven't found a particularly good approach to this specific step

Comment: The short answer is yes.  The longer answer depends upon what  "all of it" means.

Comment: all of it is that I would like to deploy the multi account configuration from code. I just don't know if that is possible @fedonev

Answer (score 0):

"Multi account configuration" will mean different things to different people.  The CDK can create Organization resources like [Accounts](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_organizations-readme.html) and IAM resources like [Users](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_iam-readme.html), if that's what you mean.  There is also a L1 CDK module for [Control Tower](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/controltower/latest/userguide/what-is-control-tower.html), AWS's account configuration orchestrator.